# jQuery Restrict End Date such that it is not more than 30 days from start Date

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery Calender code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "../../images/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          maxDate: '0',
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
          {$("#toDate").val('');
              $("#toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
          }

        });

      $( "#toDate" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
          changeMonth:true,
          changeYear:true,
          showOn: "button",
          maxDate: '0',
          buttonImage: "../../images/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true
        });
});
</script>
```

I it to be in such a way so that the no of days allowed in `#toDate` should not be more than `#fromDate + 30`

How can i do that ?

Please note both the calenders already do not allow to choose date more than current day !

Comment: Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/2y67W/,  Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425001/setting-max-date-jquery-datepicker

Comment: I am unable to follow the reference.. Can you help me.. I am new to jQuery

Comment: Actually End date have 2 restrictions it shouldn't be more than current date and it should not be more than start date + 30. Please help

Comment: The datepicker has the properties, minDate and maxDate. So u can set these properties with the required dates. below is a sample,                                                                                             var currentDate= new Date();
var maxdate = new Date(currentDate);
maxdate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 30);
$("#toDate").datepicker({                                                              
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: currentDate,
     maxDate:maxdate
}).datepicker('setDate',currentDate);

Comment: var currentDate = new Date() gives me current date. How do i replace this currentDate with from Date

Comment: Split your from date and assign it to the currenDate,                var split = fromdate.split('/');     
var currentDate = new Date(split[2], split[1], split[0]);

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker has the properties, minDate and maxDate. So u can set these properties with the required dates. below is a sample,

```
var currentDate= new Date(); 
var maxdate = new Date(currentDate); 
maxdate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 30); 
$("#toDate").datepicker({ 
changeMonth: true, 
changeYear: true, minDate: 
currentDate, maxDate:maxdate 
    }).datepicker('setDate',currentDate);
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/2y67W/  , [Setting max date jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425001/setting-max-date-jquery-datepicker)