# How to set monthRange as well as yearRange in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have datepicker where I want to set YearRange as well as MonthRange but I can set only one at a time. 
This is code snippet. I have also tried with `maxdate` and `mindate` as

```
maxDate: '+4m', minDate: '-1M'
```

This was my try for month range

```
$('#from').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: '-100:+0',
    });
```

Please help

Comment: Please explain by giving example what do exactly you  are expecting by setting **YearRange** and **MonthRange** option !

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425001/setting-max-date-jquery-datepicker#14425261) answer could help you.